# Lua random function mess

Tags: math, random, lua

I'm trying to design a game in lua (This is my first shot). And now I'm stuck with the math.random and math.randomseed() functions. I had gone through the math library, but it even confused me more. 
I want to randomize 3 functions (means I want 3 functions to be called randomly).
How do I do this with math.random() function?

Also, which random function is better and safe to use? the math.random() or math.randomseed() ?

Help please

Answer (score 2):

First - clarification. Function `random.randomseed()` **initializes** random number generator. It means that you should call it somewhere in start of your program, typically before first `random.random()` call.

Now, to solve your problem and call three functions randomly, you have to use numbers generated with `random.random()` to call these functions (numbers are from 0 to 1). This is one way to do it:

```
local function first()
    …
end
local function second()
    …
end
local function third()
    …
end

random.randomseed(os.time()) -- initialize random number generator with time

local number = random.random()
if number < 0.3333 then
    first()
elseif number < 0.6666 then
    second()
else
    third()
```

Now, you can do it in a loop, so that your functions will be called multiple times. You can also change probabilities (in the code above, in the long run, frequency of calling `first()` will be similar to `second()` and `third()`). If you need to call one of the funcitons more often, just adjust the numbers in if conditions).

Comment: Yeah! :) I figured out calling functions randomly yesterday night.
And thank you for clarification. :)